# mysql load local infile permission issues

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I am unable to use local infile to load data into mysql. The error I get is `Can't get stat of 'filename' (Errorcode:13)`.

I tried to modify the permission of the directory my file using `chmod -R 755 dir_name'` but still get the same error. Any ideas? My preferred solution would be to somehow modify ther permission of the directory containing my file, so that it can be read my mysql - but I am open to other solutions also should the need arise.

The python code I am using is below.

```
def csv_todb(filename, cursor):
    query = "load data local infile '%s' into table mytable fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' ; " % (filename) 
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: chances are its a path problem are you passing a complete path in?

Comment: When I pass the full path I get, `The used command is not allowed with this mysql version` error

Answer (score 0):

It's possible `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is disabled for security reasons.  See [--local-infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-options.html#option_mysqld_local-infile).

Comment: Sorry, I am new to mysql as well. I start mysql with --local-infile=1, and still get the same error messages.

Comment: It needs to be enabled on the server as well as the client, and you need the full path.